# Do I have to use domain controller name in LDAP path?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are using some LDAP queries in our company. Our queries produced an error and did not return any result yesterday. After realizing that we started to try to solve this problem and found something interesting. We use LDAP path like this for our queries (this style produced an error: KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED):

```
LDAP://xxx.yyy.net.tr/DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=net,DC=tr
```

After we changed the LDAP path as shown below, our queries started to work correctly:

```
LDAP://DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=net,DC=tr
```

What is the difference between two LDAP paths and why the first one does not work sometimes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the second form uses 'localhost' as the host name, with the effect of curing the problem noted [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/558115). But surely there are three slashes before the DN, not two?

Comment: thanks for your answer. we have only two slashes before DN and it is working? is that a problem?

Comment: we looked this article before and it didnt solve our problem. we are solving this issue with reastarting our computer :( (because this solution only works with standalone applications not asp.net applications)

Comment: Something has happened to that link. I don't recognize the contents now.